# I wanna create a new table from the data of two tables

Tags: php, sql

I have a A table to store the product name, the quantity and input day of goods in stock. In adverse conditions, invoices for the above products will be sent later. I will put the product name and invoice quantity in B table. The problem here is that I want to check the quantity of goods with invoice and without invoice. Updating goods with invoices will follow FIFO.

Example:

**Table A**

| id | good_id | num | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 2021-09-24 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 2021-09-25 |

**Table B**

| id | good_id | num_invoice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 12 |

I solved it by creating a new C table with the same data as the A table

**Table C**

| id | good_id | current_number | created_at | invoice_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 2021-09-24 | null |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 2021-09-25 | null |

Then I get the data in table B group by good_id and store it in $data.
Using php to foreach $data and check condition:

**I updated C table ORDER BY `created_at` DESC limit 1 as follows:**

- if (`tableC`.`current_num` - `$data['num']` < 0) then update `current_number`  = 0, `invoice_number` = `$data['num']` - `tableC`.`current_num`. Update value `$data['num']` = `$data['num']` - `tableC`.`current_num`
- if (`tableC`.`current_num` - `$data['num']` > 0) or (`tableC`.`current_num` - $data['num'] = 0) then update `current_number`  = `tableC`.`current_num` - `$data['num']`, `invoice_number` = `$data['num']`.

**table C after update**

| id | good_id | current_number | created_at | invoice_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 2021-09-24 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2021-09-25 | 2 |

I solved the problem with `php` like that. However, with a dataset of about 100,000 rows, I think the backend processing will take a long time. Can someone give me a smarter way to handle this?

Comment: What database and version are you using (MariaDB 10.5, MySQL 8.x, SQL Server 2019, PostgreSQL 16, etc)?

Comment: looks like you can JOIN these 2 tables no ?

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.7

Comment: @nhhthong Check out the updated answer, which contains a solution for MySQL 5.7+ too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated solution for MySQL 5.7:**

Test case to support MySQL 5.7+, PG, MariaDB prior to 10.2.2, etc:

[Test case for MySQL 5.7+, etc](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=92b23bcab5f79fa8456b96a1cda3eb20)

For MySQL 5.7:
This replaces the window function (for running SUM) and uses derived tables instead of `WITH clause`.

```
SELECT id, good_id
     , num - GREATEST(num - GREATEST(balance, 0), 0) AS num
     , created_at
     , GREATEST(num - GREATEST(balance, 0), 0) AS invoice_num
  FROM (
         SELECT MIN(t2.id) AS id, MIN(t2.num) AS num
              , t2.good_id, t2.created_at
              , MIN(o.num_invoice) AS num_invoice
              , SUM(t1.num) - MIN(o.num_invoice) AS balance
           FROM tableA AS t1
           JOIN tableA AS t2
             ON t1.good_id = t2.good_id
            AND t1.created_at <= t2.created_at
           JOIN (
                   SELECT good_id, SUM(num_invoice) AS num_invoice
                     FROM tableB
                    GROUP BY good_id
                ) AS o
             ON o.good_id = t1.good_id
          GROUP BY t2.good_id, t2.created_at
       ) AS cte2
 ORDER BY created_at
;
```

For databases that handle functional dependence in `GROUP BY` properly, we could just `GROUP BY t2.id` (the `primary key` of `tableA`) and remove the `MIN(t2.id)` and the `MIN(t2.num)`.

Like this:

[Test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=48009f981c69d2eac05eb9cf08a2fcd2)

```
-- For MySQL 5.7
SELECT id, good_id
     , num - GREATEST(num - GREATEST(balance, 0), 0) AS num
     , created_at
     , GREATEST(num - GREATEST(balance, 0), 0) AS invoice_num
  FROM (
         SELECT t2.id, t2.num
              , t2.good_id, t2.created_at
              , MIN(o.num_invoice) AS num_invoice
              , SUM(t1.num) - MIN(o.num_invoice) AS balance
           FROM tableA AS t1
           JOIN tableA AS t2
             ON t1.good_id = t2.good_id
            AND t1.created_at <= t2.created_at
           JOIN (
                   SELECT good_id, SUM(num_invoice) AS num_invoice
                     FROM tableB
                    GROUP BY good_id
                ) AS o
             ON o.good_id = t1.good_id
          GROUP BY t2.id
       ) AS cte2
 ORDER BY created_at
;
```

**Original Answer using window functions and `WITH clause`:**

Here's a test case with PG 13, but works fine with MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10.2.2+.

Note: I left this as just a query that generates the requested detail.  It's not clear the 3rd table is necessary.  This can be used to update (or create) that table, if needed.

Test case:

[Working test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=23f4b05e3b841711df7daf10d7eeb898)

CTE terms:

1. cte1 - calculate the total requested goods
2. cte2 - Calculate the running balance based on running inventory by date

Finally, we use cte2 to determine the goods allocated and remaining, requested by the question.

```
WITH cte1 (good_id, num_invoice) AS (
        SELECT good_id, SUM(num_invoice) AS num_invoice
          FROM tableB
         GROUP BY good_id
     )
   , cte2 AS (
       SELECT a.*, o.num_invoice
            , SUM(num) OVER (PARTITION BY a.good_id ORDER BY created_at) - o.num_invoice AS balance
         FROM tableA AS a
         JOIN cte1   AS o
           ON o.good_id = a.good_id
     )
SELECT id, good_id
     , num - GREATEST(num - GREATEST(balance, 0), 0) AS num
     , created_at
     , GREATEST(num - GREATEST(balance, 0), 0) AS invoice_num
  FROM cte2
 ORDER BY created_at
;
```

The result:

```
+----+---------+------+------------+-------------+
| id | good_id | num  | created_at | invoice_num |
+----+---------+------+------------+-------------+
|  1 |       1 |    0 | 2021-09-24 |          10 |
|  2 |       1 |    3 | 2021-09-25 |           2 |
|  3 |       1 |    7 | 2021-09-26 |           0 |
+----+---------+------+------------+-------------+
```

Note: I added one additional onhand entry for 7 goods (id = 3) to test an edge case.

Setup of the test case:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
   id           int primary key
 , good_id      int
 , num          int
 , created_at   date
);

CREATE TABLE tableB (
   id           int primary key
 , good_id      int
 , num_invoice  int
);

INSERT INTO tableA VALUES
  (1,1,10,'2021-09-24')
, (2,1, 5,'2021-09-25')
, (3,1, 7,'2021-09-26')
;

INSERT INTO tableB VALUES
  (1,1,12)
;
```

Comment: thank you very much. This is great idea. however, the system I'm using is MYSQL 5.7. But this is also a good idea when I upgrade MYSQL later.

Comment: @nhhthong This can be done in MySQL 5.7 too ...  One moment.